# dependent on PATH variables, but dont want to install in PATH. How?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, tesseract, poppler

So I have a python library that is dependent on PyTesseractOCR and on Poppler. Both of these should be installed and in PATH. But I dont like that the end user will have to install multiple other libraries into PATH as its not very user-friendly.

How can I use these programs without demanding the user to install them and put them in path?

I have tried putting the folders in my own Pypi 'src' folder to ship them together with the rest of the code, but:

- PyTesseractOCR has a path-director like this `pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'src\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'` but is way too big for pypi's standards (450MB instead of 100MB limit).
- Poppler doesnt seem to have a path-director function like Tesseract does.

I have also tried to look online for adding them to PYTHONPATH but it is unclear to me if this can work, or if its a recommended way of doing things.

Any other ideas are very welcome

---

ChatGPT has these two recommendations:

1. Update setup.py
   Open your setup.py file and add the following lines at the top, below the existing imports:

```py
import subprocess

# Install Poppler and PyTesseract using pip
subprocess.run(["pip", "install", "poppler-utils>=0.70.0", "pytesseract>=0.3.8"])
```

2. Update pyproject.toml
   Open your pyproject.toml file and add the following lines under the [build-system] section:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.6"
poppler-utils = "^0.70.0"
pytesseract = "^0.3.8"
```

Comment: Have you considered downloading the dependent libraries as part of your setup?

Comment: See for example how `pymupdf` [does it](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/blob/730da1601396af9e0f7f179f7109837ab5b47429/setup.py#L431)

Comment: Thanks @FlyingTeller that looks promising. Is there a step-by-step tutorial or explanation somewhere on what is really happening there?